# React-Router V6 issue, only the root "/" route works, any other endpoint returns a 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a React app with multiple pages with React-Router V6. There seems to be an issue with the paths. Whenever I try running the code in my browser, any other path besides the root ("/"), returns a 404. Meaning that it doesn't exist.
Here are snippets of the files I'm using:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App.js';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

// Components
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Router from './Router';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div id='app'>
      <Router />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import Login from './Login';
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import History from './History';
import Home from './Home';

const Router = () => {
  return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='/history' element={<History />} />
    <Route path='/checkout' element={<Checkout />} />
  </Routes>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './NavBar';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div id='home'>
      <NavBar />
      <h1>Homepage</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Every other component's jsx code `<Login>, <History>` etc.. is identical to the `<Home>` one, other than the text in the `<h1>` tag

This is what happens when I open the root page
[/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tygrp.jpg)

This is what happens when I open any other endpoint [/checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7txny.jpg) [/login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr8br.jpg)

If this isn't enough information....
I can't make a minimal reproducible example as it takes too many files to create an up and running fullstack javascript application. But I can give you the link to the repo and some instructions on how to reproduce the issue.
link: https://github.com/Lawsan92/pizzaOrder

1. Fork and clone the repo
2. open the file in any IDE
3. Navigate to the server.js file and replace process.env.PORT with any port 3000 (or anything else)
4. in the root directory run `npm run server`
5. Open whichever browser you use and go to localhost:3000
6. The test the other endpoints localhost:3000/login localhost:3000/checkout etc..

Here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

const clientCofig = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './client/src/index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './client/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /nodeModules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = clientCofig;
```

Comment: Which v6?  v6.4 has major breaking changes.

Comment: For example: the <Routes> is now <Route> and the return is return <RouterProvider router={router} /> if using the new data api's.  Also, there is a space between the named element and ending bracket so element={<Home/>} should be element={<Home />}

Comment: If 6.4 well, the docs tend to be out of date or missing.  Hopefully they will be updated soon.

Comment: @Optionwiz I don't know what you are referring to with RRDv6.4.... it introduced no breaking changes from anything else already in RRDv6. (*Well, that's not entirely true, they did change the navigationContext*) What it ***did*** do was to add [new Data APIs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router), which introduced ***new*** router/routing utilities/capabilities, most of which have to do with fetching data when navigating to a route and handling routing errors. The docs on the main branch are up-to-date and current.

Comment: @DrewReese there are actually breaking changes in 6.4 vs 6.3.  The GitHub issues tracker is full of discussions both open and closed.  History is well.. history going forward and many of the examples in 6.4 haven't been updated yet to reflect the new data api's.  v6.4.3 is suppose to fix the docs/examples in a week or so.

Comment: @Optionwiz I apologize, I guess I should've included the package.json, anyway IT IS 6.4...more specifically: "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"

Comment: @Optionwiz FWIW it seems most of the "breaking changes" are based on internal implementation details that were warned about from the start with RRDv6. The RRD maintainers finally made some implementation changes and devs are upset. It's not like there's a major version update, which usually indicates actual breaking changes to the public APIs. Like I said though... all the existing components still work exactly the same (*as far as I am aware of*).

Comment: Ok, so its going to be a bit different than most of the examples or tutorials out there that use 6.3 or earlier api's.  There are a couple of vids on YouTube that are free and go over RRD6.4 and the changes from 6.0-6.3.  Here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2kzUg6IzxM

Comment: @DrewReese yes, the major breaking change was originally 6.0 when the roadmap didn't include history or custom histories or navigating outside of the context of the current app (think MFE with module federation - a major use case for RRD).  But now that 2/3 have adopted 6.X from 5.X using the temp migration fixes, the maintainers went back to the original roadmap for 6.0 when they released 6.4 and many are stuck at 6.3 unless they can learn to work with the new data api's.  From the maintainers viewpoint its data api's going forward. Hidden deprecation notices in 6.4.0-pre.. bread crumbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack configuration needs to redirect all page requests to the root index.html file. You can do this by specifying a public path in the output and adding `historyApiFallback: true,` in the configuration. You'll also need to update the `server.js` file to handle nested page requests.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

const clientCofig = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './client/src/index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './client/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/' // <-- add public path here
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true // <-- add fallback here
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /nodeModules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = clientCofig;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('hello world');
})

app.get('https://order-pizza-api.herokuapp.com/api/orders', (req, res) => {
  console.log('res.body:', res.body);
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')))

app.get('/*', function(req, res) { // <-- add
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening to port: ${process.env.PORT}`)
})

app.use(express.json());
```

The other issue I found was in your `NavBar` component. It's rendering raw anchor tags `<a>` instead of the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`. Import the `Link` component and replace all anchor tags with the `Link` component and switch the `href` attribute to the `to` prop.

/src/components/NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='nav'>
      <Link to='/' className='site-title'>
        Site Title
      </Link>
      <ul>
        <li className='active'>
          <Link to='/pricing'>Pricing</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
        <Link to='/history'>About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt but sadly the endpoints still aren't working. I even stopped and relaunched the npm server. I also relaunched vscode...because you never know

Comment: @ls170292 I pulled down your repo and made the above changes to your code, rebuild the app, and then ran the server and the links in the navbar correctly navigate within the app. The only link you are rendering a route for though, *other than `"/"`, is the `"/history" route with the `History` component which is the "About" link in the header/navbar.

Comment: What I find puzzling is that when I access these endpoints by directly typing in the url in the browser search bar it still returns the same errors message 'cannot GET /endpoint other than the root'. However, when I navigate to these endpoints by clicking on the <Link> components, the GET request is successful.

Comment: @ls170292 Yeah, noticed that as well myself. I'm looking at your `server.js` file now to see what routes it handles.

Comment: Is it because React-Router-Dom is client side routing? Meaning that these routes don't exist in the server-side code? Even when I run curl -GET 'localhost:3000/login', the GET request still fails.

Comment: I didn't write any other endpoint handlers apart from the root "/"and "/test". I didn't think/know that would be necessary. I thought that RRD would take care of that.

Comment: @ls170292 Yes, RRD is all client-side routing... there're still the edge cases where the user directly navigates to one of the nested routes or reloads the page and a page request is made to the server. This is where the server redirecting all page requests to the root index.html file so the React app can load and then handle the routing to the correct page internally comes into play. I've updated my answer to include also the change to your `server.js` file.

Comment: Bless you sir! It works perfectly now. I was following a similar train of thought but I couldn't figure out the correct res method to redirect the requests. I never would've guessed that I would run into an issue this complex. All I wanted to do was make a simple multi paged web application with react but I'm grateful to have had the opportunity to learn so much. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this. Cheers!

Comment: @ls170292 No worries. Webpack is a little opaque to me as well. I had the `app.get('/*', ....)` in there for a while and it just wasn't working... finally realized it needed to be specified *after* the `app.use(....)` line. ‍♂️ Glad to help, cheers and good luck!

Comment: @ls170292 FWIW, and to give you an idea of "complexity", you should take a look at the `create-react-app` [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a sense of how each different server environment possibly uses a different configuration to handle routing/navigation.