# react-router-dom and express, main.js file fetching gone wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router-dom

I`m using express, webpack and react client.

I made the route for the html as in the example, so I have this in my server.js:

```
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '../dist');
const HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html');

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(HTML_FILE);
});
```

With simple routes in react-router-dom, like "/home", "/" it works fine, but when I add second level  to path - "/s/page", getting this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.js:1:1)

In network I see that it tries to get main.js from http://localhost:3000/s/main.js and got index.html file (because of "*" route I think).

How can I handle this properly

Also, webpack config, maybe it helps:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    target: 'web',
    plugins: [htmlPlugin],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    }
};
```

I tried to add custom route for main.js file like this:

```
const JS_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'main.js');
app.get(/^.*\/main\.js$/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(JS_FILE);
});
```

And seems like it works, but with this I can`t debug code, and don`t think this is best solution

Comment: What does your HTML template look like? It's likely because the plugin does `<script src="main.js">` instead of `<script src="/main.js">`.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74168241/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese thanks! I looked through many different questions on stackoverflow but didn't find anything similar to mine, but this solution solved my problem