# React router throwing Cannot GET /info

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I want to render a component using React Router, The component responsibility is just to show the JSON object containing build information (commitHash, branch, version, etc).

The problem is whenever I access http://localhost:3000/info to get the build information, it is treated as a backend API call and throws 404 error (

```
Cannot GET /info
```

) ,

I am using the express-actuator package in the server.dev.js file, I am guessing something we have to change in the server.dev.js file because it is treating the /info as a server call instead of rendering the component

Below is a code snippet

```
require('dotenv-flow').config();
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const actuator = require('express-actuator');

const app = express(),
    DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html');
const config = require('./webpack.dev.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(
  webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  })
);

app.use(
  webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  })
);

app.use(actuator({ basePath: "/actuator" }));

app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(HTML_FILE);
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
   
    console.log(`\nError in server setup: ${err}`);
  }
  
  console.log(`\nServer started on Port: ${port}...`);
});
```

and /webpack.dev.config.js fil

```
const DotenvFlow = require('dotenv-flow-webpack');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const { GitRevisionPlugin } = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin');
const gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin();

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
            './src/main/index.tsx'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        globalObject: 'this'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'web',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                test: /(\.css)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                exclude: [
                    /\.module\.s[ac]ss$/,
                    /\.libs\.s[ac]ss$/,
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: false,
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            }, {
                test: /\.module\.s[ac]ss$/,
                exclude: [
                    /\.libs\.s[ac]ss$/,
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.libs\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf)$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.tsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            '_GIT_VERSION_': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.version()),
            '_GITSHA_': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()),
            '_GIT_BRANCH_': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.branch()),
            '_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP_': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.lastcommitdatetime())
        }),
        new DotenvFlow(),
        new WebpackManifestPlugin({ publicPath: "" }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),
        gitRevisionPlugin,
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/main/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

my App.tsx file

```
import React from "react";
import HomeComponent from "./components/HomeComponent";
import {Routes , Route } from "react-router-dom"
import BuildInfoPopper from "./components/BuildInfoPopper";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/info" element={<BuildInfoPopper/>}/>
      </Routes>
     
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

and index.tsx file

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import BuildInfoPopper from "./components/BuildInfoPopper";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = document.getElementById("root");

const rootElement = (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);

render(rootElement, root);
```

I have tried keeping the wild card character in server.dev.js but it didn't work

Comment: Is accessing `http://localhost:3000/info` a typo? Everything else in the question implies there's an issue accessing the single `"/build"` route the app is rendering.

Comment: Sorry, That is just a typo.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74168241/8690857

Comment: No, it is redirecting to index.html which eventually lands in homePage, But I want to render the React BuildInfoPopper component when /info is called, How can we let React know first look at the React Routes if any /info routes are available and then only go and check in express routes? is there any way to do that?

Comment: Since I am using React router along with express, The calls are routed to express and not looking into React router, is there any way where we can override the express with React router?

Comment: If the server is correctly handling all page requests and serving the root index.html file, then the React app should be rendered and correctly internally handling routing/navigation to the `"/info"` route it is rendering. Why would your React app need to search backend express routes? There should only be the one single route serving up the app, all the other routing occurs on the client side in the browser in the app. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you, Drew Reese, it was my build issue, The bundle.js was not properly built. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help, however little it may've been. Cheers.