# React Router V6: Cannot GET route

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm attempting to set up some basic routing but when I attempt to navigate to my `Drug` link, I get a "Cannot GET {route}". I'm unsure as to why this occurs, and I'd appreciate if anyone could explain what I should be doing differently.

```
// Router inside of App component

const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path="/" element={
            <RxNormProvider>
                <Search />
            </RxNormProvider>
        }>
            <Route path="/info/:rxcui" element={
                <RxNormProvider>
                    <Drug />
                </RxNormProvider>
            }/>
        </Route>
    )
);
---
// Drug component

<Link to={`/info/${drug.rxcui}`}>
...
</Link>
```

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
                type: 'asset/inline',
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "./public/index.html")
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new WebpackDev.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.name': JSON.stringify('dev')
        }),
    ],
};
```

**EDIT #1:** Added webpack configuration. I serve this application using the following command:

`"start": "webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.config.ts --env env=development --open"`

`env` denotes which environment we are deploying into, but I have not included it into the code because I don't think it relates to the problem.

Comment: How are you hosting/serving your application? This appears to be an issue with the way the server is setup/configured to serve the app. The client-side routing is a bit irrelevant since the app needs to be served first to the client before any client-side routing can occur.

Comment: I'm just trying to test everything on my local machine; I don't have it hosted at the moment.

Comment: So how are you running the app then?

Comment: I'm using webpack to serve it. My bad, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Can you [edit] to share your webpack configuration, the commands you are using to build and run/serve the app locally, and any other information/details/code you think might be relevant for us to know. See [mcve].

Comment: Just added webpack configuration. I didn't think webpack related to the issue so I did not add it in initially.

Comment: I think I dug into it. I looked into webpack with react router, and it looks like I needed some settings added to my configuration. i'm still not getting my page to render properly, but I no longer get the cannot get route error. will update if i make further progress

Comment: Yup. Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74168241/8690857

Comment: I made the changes but my page does not render the ``Drug`` component; it just re-renders the ``Search`` component.

Comment: Try wrapping <Route>  within `<Routes> </Routes>`

Comment: Still does not render the new page. Just redirects me to the root page.

Comment: My router is like this , in case it helps 
 `export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <div >

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePageFlightContainer/>} /> 
                <Route path="/search" element={<RenderTopMenuResultPage />}
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
};`.  and I use like  `<a href="#" className="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px"
                     onClick={handleSearch }
                      >
                      Search Now
                    </a>`

Comment: `let navigate = useNavigate();
   function handleSearch() {
    console.log("inside handle search::");
     navigate('/search');

  }`

Comment: Are you saying that no matter what route you try to access that the URL changes to `"/"` and only the root route loads and renders? Or does the URL change to `"/info/someValue"`? Does the `Search` component render an `Outlet` for the nested route to render its `element` content out?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, using `Routes` and un-nesting the 2 `Route` elements solved the issue.

I'll have to research nested routing but for now, thank you to those who contributed.